# How is application ID used by Xcode when building/signing the application?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uniqueidentifier, ios-provisioning

iOS Provisioning files make reference to the Apple application ID (of the form "A1A2A3A4A5"). Most often, the DNS form of the application is replaced with a star (*).

My understanding is that the provisioning profile is stored in the iOS development device and is not used by Xcode. Thus, when building/signing the application, how can Xcode include the app ID into the executable file ? The only information Xcode has is the "Bundle Identifier", which is of the form "com.mycompany.myapp" - but there is no App ID, thus there is no way to add the app ID at this stage.

Does anyone know how this works. I feel that many people use those tools (as I do) without really knowing how it's made inside.

Many Regards,
Apple92

Answer (score 2):

An iPhone application is not just an executable, it's a bundle (like a directory) that contains the executable, but also resources (like nibs or images) and in particular contains a small plist manifest file with details about your application - including the application ID.  The provisioning profile is also included in this application bundle.

A device also maintains a list of provisioning profiles it has installed, but the profiles can be in the application as well and are checked against the application plist file to make sure everything matches.

Comment: I tried to search in the plist file (the one visible in Xcode) but I cannot find any app ID tag.

Comment: It's the Bundle Identifier (contains the app ID that needs to match the profile, at least the prefix).  By default it's com.yourcompany.

Comment: I do not understand: the Apple portal shows my app ID like this: xxxxxxxx.com.yourcompany.myapp (or xxxxxxx.*). Why do not I see xxxxxxxx in the Bundle identifier?

Comment: Finally this is explained here by Apple:

Comment: @user255607 : where is it explained ??

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who may stumble upon this question, I give a lot of detailed context in my answer to this related question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20557213/117471

Basically it boils down to this:

1. A Bundle ID is a string that is defined in Xcode
2. An App ID is an object that lives in Developer Member Center. It is often confused with Bundle ID because the App ID Suffix parameter of the object *(I'm trying to drive home the fact that App ID is not a string. Is it working?)* matches the Bundle ID of your app.
3. The App ID does not exist in iTunes Connect, or Xcode. It is only in Developer Member Center.