# Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app yet they are identical

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing

An app extension is causing a code signing issue.  This app is  already  on the Appstore (with this extension) yet overnight for some reason when I have come back to this app im  getting[image]

A strange error as its contradicting itself by showing two exact identical certificates in said error message.

Ive tried 
clean and restart, deleting derived data, regenerating  provisioning profiles, deleting and creating new profiles. using both xcode 6.1 and xcode beta and [This](http://aplus.rs/2014/embedded-binary-is-not-signed-with-the-same-certificate-as-the-parent-app/)

I have also searched SO [Xcode6:Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927604/xcode6embedded-binary-is-not-signed-with-the-same-certificate-as-the-parent-app) and no solutions offered worked

(Deleting the app extension removes the error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So if anyone comes across this cryptic message the "App Group" switch in Capabilities of the app extension was off for some reason.   Turned it back on and all good.  Fix any "issues" if it requires you to when you do this

Answer (score 2):

I have tried the following solution is working this morning! Please try it!

> The only solution here was that I went to Developer Portal, removed
>   all profiles, then removed all downloaded profiles through Finder, did
>   Clean project and Clean Build folder, closed and re-opened Xcode.
>
> Then I opened my project, went to both app and extension targets - at which
>   point Xcode realized no profiles are present and thus goes to
>   Developer Portal to get them. Since there’s nothing to download, it
>   goes through each App ID you have on your account and creates
>   development profile for each one.

http://aplus.rs/2014/embedded-binary-is-not-signed-with-the-same-certificate-as-the-parent-app/

Comment: Oh my god you just saved me after hours of frustration. Never thought to Clean Build Folder. 10/10 would up vote again.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that I had a Copy Files post-build step that was causing the issue (somehow).

Once I removed that Copy Files phase, this error went away..

Comment: Same issue; Copy Files build phase works fine the first run, then subsequently causes this error. https://stackoverflow.com/a/51622093/1265393

Answer (score 1):

When I had this issue I went to the Apple Member Center and realized that the Provisioning Profile (for the extension) that I had created was marked as 'Invalid'. I just re-created the Provisioning Profile with the same certificate that the app is signed with and then downloaded it via Xcode > Preferences > Account > refresh.

Once I had the new provisioning profiles I selected them in the build settings. I selected the provisioning profile that was just created and also selected the corresponding certificate in the Code signing entity in the build settings and that fixed the issue.

Note that the extension has its own app id and hence its own provisioning profile.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was not having the App Groups set up correctly on all my App IDs on the Developer Portal. Therefor the App Groups in the app didn't work correctly, causing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

What fixed this for me was:

1. Re-Logging to my accounts in Preferences -> Accounts.
2. Turning App Groups OFF in both (main app + keyboard extension) Targets (under Target -> Capabilities), then turning them back ON and re-selecting/re-checking the app groups.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. This started on the day when my Certificate got expired after a year. Following steps worked for me:

1. Delete the old expired certificate from Keychain(You will be able to see a red cross on the certificate icon)
2. Restarting your mac