# Always 'Ad Hoc Code Signed' for Embedded Binary Signing Certificate

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing, provisioning-profile, ios-extensions

I have two targets, the main target & an extension target. Now when I'm trying to archive the app, Xcode failed with the following error:

```
error: Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app. Verify the embedded binary target's code sign settings match the parent app's.

        Embedded Binary Signing Certificate:    - (Ad Hoc Code Signed)
        Parent App Signing Certificate:     iPhone Distribution: ***. (EAA28CVMQM)
```

So I checked the `Build Settings - Code Signing` again and again to ensure `Embedded binary is signed with the same certificate as the parent app`,

[image]

[image]

Or settings like below :

[image]

They all failed into the same reason. No matter how I change the Code Signing settings, the `Embedded Binary Signing Certificate` is always `(Ad Hoc Code Signed)`.

Before this post, I've read these links:

[Xcode6:Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25927604/xcode6embedded-binary-is-not-signed-with-the-same-certificate-as-the-parent-app)

[Embedded binary is not signed with the same certificate as the parent app yet they are identical](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27273911/embedded-binary-is-not-signed-with-the-same-certificate-as-the-parent-app-yet-th)

http://aplus.rs/2014/embedded-binary-is-not-signed-with-the-same-certificate-as-the-parent-app/

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2407/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40014991-CH1-VALIDATION_ERRORS-EMBEDDED_BINARY_S_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER_IS_NOT_PREFIXED_WITH_THE_PARENT_APP_S_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER_

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Believe it or not!!!!!!!!!!!!

It's the `Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority`, if I choose `always trust`, Xcode archives failed. When I changed to `system defaults`, Xcode archives successfully.

Bloody h...

Comment: It's also a truth for any certificates you are going to use for building. Thanks Jason Lee.

Comment: i stuck here from two weeks, you saved me alot. Thakns @Jason Lee

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: OMG,I stuck here for tow days,Thank you so much!

Comment: What!!??!!! [No.](https://media.giphy.com/media/11NBUrJDuMd5As/giphy.gif)

Comment: Go the same error on Xcode8. I couldn't use "always trust" on related certificates but setting the private key to allow any application was OK for me.

Comment: Thanks!! It helps me a lot!

Comment: why? like why? it's so dumb, is there any valid reason?

Answer (score 5):

***It's the Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority issues.
Here How to solve error step by step***

- Open  Keychain Access
- Select your certificate
- Right click on certificate and click Get Info
- Where you find option trust - When Using Certificate - Select Use
  System Defaults

Answer (score 5):

I had this problem when building for iOS Simulator (for device everything was OK).
This has helped me, while none of SO answers did:

> The problem had nothing to do with the signing. The answer for me was
>   to paste $(ARCHS_STANDARD) into the project valid architecture field.
>   Incredible!

(c) https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/107563

Comment: This is worked for me. I set `$(ARCHS_STANDARD)` this as Valid Architecture for all my targets and removed all other options like armv6, armv7.

Comment: What a goose chase... same solution.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue while working with shared extensions. Even after editing the AWDRC certificate I kept on getting the same error on Xcode 7. However once I upgraded to Xcode 7.2 the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was because I had one installation on `Computer A` and have used Xcode on `Computer B` and had asked me to revoke the certificate. I didn't know how to re-revoke it on `Computer A` and have googled stuff for 3 hours until I have tried to quit and reopen Xcode. It has immediately asked me to revoke the certificate and everything is working again.

Xcode is awful.