# How to fix this Xcode Error: "Warning unable to build chain to self signed root for signer apple Development"?

Tags: ios, xcode

So, I just renewed my Apple developer membership and I started getting this error `"Warning  unable to build chain to self signed root for signer apple Development"`.

I am unable to archive my apps in order to upload them to the AppStore, I tried these threads with no luck:

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/86161

[Always 'Ad Hoc Code Signed' for Embedded Binary Signing Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30096022/always-ad-hoc-code-signed-for-embedded-binary-signing-certificate)

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/662300

PS: I have `"this certificate is not trusted"` in my Apple development and Apple Distribution certificates in the Certificates section on the keychain access. I don't know if that is related to my issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What worked for me was to download the `"Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority"` that expires in 20 Feb 2030 along side with the already existent one that expires in 7 Feb 2023.

That was enough to make the `"this certificate is not trusted"` go away, and to let me build and archive my app again.

Comment: I also download/install the new certificate and the problem was solved... here is the link to download https://developer.apple.com/support/expiration/

Comment: This was the solution for me doing Xamarin development on VS for Mac

Comment: Yeah this works for Xamarin

Comment: Worked for a Unity build on my end.

Comment: This answer solved my problem getting the "unable to build chain to self signed root for signer" warning/error when trying to use `codesign_identity` in PyInstaller after I got a new laptop. I downloaded and installed the G3 certificate expiring 2/20/2030 in Keychain Access (in addition to adding my own certificated).

Answer (score 3):

I have this issue recently and I have found out that this is a problem with the OS.
This solution seems like a hack but it works!

0. Go to Xcode **Preferences** menu (<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) and then **Accounts** tab
1. click on the gear icon on the bottom left and **Export Apple ID and Code Signing Assets...**
   [image: Settings]
2. Set a password for the export

> ⚠️ You are going to delete all passwords and profiles! Don't forget your password! Writing down your password is highly recommended.

> ⛔️ This file will contain all your accounts and profiles. Make sure to keep it very secure.

3. Delete all accounts.
4. Build and face the new error.
5. Import them back using your password.

It's should working again now.

Comment: I tried this but did not work for me, maybe it'll work for someone else. I still get the same error.