# .NET MAUI app publish failing to sign on iOS

Tags: certificate, maui, .net-7.0

I am trying to deploy my application to iOS. The application is a .NET MAUI (net7.0) application that works flawless on Android, and in debug for iOS, but now that I am trying to deploy the application with "dotnet publish" I get the following error:

```
    Warning: unable to build chain to self-signed root for signer "iPhone Distribution: MyCertificate (*****)"
  /Users/myuser/Documents/repos/MyApp.App-MAUI/MyApp.App/bin/Release/net7.0-ios/ios-arm64/MyApp.App.app: errSecInternalComponent
```

It worked when I deployed from a MacInCloud instance, but now I am using a real MacBook Pro instead but cannot get it to work. I have tried creating a new certificate, provisioning profile but still the same error, I have also tried to change the "always trust" on the certificate to "use system default" but no difference.

Thanks in advance!

Best regards Max

Comment: The problem in this link is similar to yours, you can refer to the solution in the link：[How to fix this Xcode Error: "Warning unable to build chain to self signed root for signer apple Development"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67648049/how-to-fix-this-xcode-error-warning-unable-to-build-chain-to-self-signed-root)

Comment: Not sure it is related, but I got this "unable to build chain..." error, and what I did was, replace some expired certificates on my MAC.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer:

You are most likely missing the Worldwide Developer Relations certificate.
Just navigate to https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/, go to the "Apple Intermediate Certificates"-section, select the correct "Worldwide Developer Relations - G..", download it and install it.
This should fix your problem.

The long answer:

For others needing to do this at a later point I've created a list of the steps for acquiring/installing a valid apple certificate.

1. Create sign request from your Mac.
2. Upload it to your apple developer account to create a Certificate.
   https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/certificates/list
3. Download the created certificate to you Mac and double-click it to install it.
4. Go to "Keychain Access" and find your certificate in "login -> My Certificates" and select it.
5. You are finished if the you select the certificate and it say "This certificate is valid". If not, you most likely haven't installed the "Worldwide Developer Relations" certificate. Then continue with the next steps..
6. Double click the certificate you installed and have a look at the "Issuer Name" section. You should see something like this: **Common Name**: *Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority*
   **Organisational Unit**: *G3*
7. Now go to: https://www.apple.com/certificateauthority/ and download the correct "Apple Intermediate Certificates"
8. Install it to your Keychain, it will be visible in "login -> Certificates"
9. Your initial certificate should now say "This certificate is valid"

The bottom line is this. A Mac must have the "Worldwide Developer Relations"-certificate
to verify the validity of your certificate.