# Xamarin iOS: How can I find the template to create a notification service extension in VS 2019 for Windows?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm following the instructions on [Enhanced User Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=windows) to show an image in a remote push notification. However, it looks like the below screen does not exist in Visual Studio. I'm using version 16.4.3. I also couldn't find it in the Extensions window in VS. Do I need to install anything to get the templates shown below? Looking at VS Installer, I have pretty much every Xamarin component installed.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The screenshot you shared is in **Visual-Studio 2017**.

In **Visual-Studio 2019**, it's here:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Is there a video that could walk me through the process of setting up a notification service extension? I need to know if I have to create a separate provisioning profile and a certificate.

Comment: @user246392 I don't know if there is a video, you can check answers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25329510/ios8-extension-needs-own-provisioning-profile) about your question.