# What is Xcode's Organization Identifier?

Tags: xcode, app-store

I have some questions around the Organization Identifier when creating a new project in Xcode.

[image: Creation of new project in Xcode]

With a quick search, I have found that the Organization Identifier is used to identify your app.

My questions are the following:

1. Should I choose a unique identifier between my apps or between developers?
2. Usually, the `com` at the beginning of the identifier is used to identify that the following word describes a company? Is that something to do with the domain-notation like `org`, `net` etc?
3. Finally, any suggestions when creating this identifier? What problems can this identifier create if not set properly in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Organization Identifier needs to be unique. Usually, is the developer's website in reverse DNS notation. That is, if the developer's website is `example.com`, then the Organization Identifier will become `com.example`.

According to Apple, this Bundle Identifier should be unique among the apps on the App Store (if you want to distribute your app on Apple's App Store). Therefore, one way to ensure this uniqueness is to choose a unique Organisation Identifier.

Creating two versions of your application (iOS, macOS) then the identifier needs also to be different, and one way is to append `.Mac` or `.iOS` before the App name in the Identifier field.

Once the App is distributed to the App Store, the identifier can't be changed.

Finally, for the last question, I can't see any problems with this part. Choosing a good, unique and nice looking Organisation Identifier is more than enough.

**References**

- [What is the difference between the app ID and the bundle ID? Where is the app ID in the Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271884/what-is-the-difference-between-the-app-id-and-the-bundle-id-where-is-the-app-i)
- [Xcode: What is the significance of a project's organization identifier?](https://www.quora.com/Xcode/What-is-the-significance-of-a-projects-organization-identifier)
- [Configure your Xcode Project for Distribution](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html)

Comment: Under one Apple account, is it possible to submit apps under two organization identifiers?