# ios application Authorization Flow?

Tags: ios, swift, authentication, authorization

I am new to iOS. I want to build an application with authentication/authorization But I am confused.
**Get requst token** 
When someone download my apps from iTunes store.why need to get request token before he log in.
**userID**
When user successfully done login? Then he will get sessionID okay. What is the userID here?

Please any help me to understand. Please describe your own voice. The picture does not matter what are presenting

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are following OAuth then you need to get request token from the server, through this request token you will be having access to rest of the api methods. That is the reason you need to first get Request token

You can check more regarding oauth here.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OAuth

Comment: that is your systems user_id a primary key to uniquely identify users

Comment: bro one more question please  don't mind . what is the app_id ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271884/what-is-the-difference-between-the-app-id-and-the-bundle-id-where-is-the-app-i

Comment: when should i request for token ? when apps loaded or user enter the username and password press login button . i am confuse about when it should do that ?

Comment: ideally before calling the 1st api.

Comment: "OAuth is a service that is complementary to and distinct from OpenID. OAuth is also distinct from OATH, which is a reference architecture for authentication, not a standard for authorization". could you share any standard for authorization ?