# should my app id need to be same in the next version release of the current ios application

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, apple-developer

i have a ios application which is live with a app id ex-123.com and the i created new app id ex-987.com and generated my certificates based on the new app id and build the app based on the new app id.Now if iam updating the app in itunes connect does it reflect the current app or it will create new app in appstore account because of new app id?

Comment: It will be a new app

Comment: it is app id or bundle identifier you are talking about?

Comment: app id but tell me the cases for both app id and bundle identifier

Comment: refer this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4271884/what-is-the-difference-between-the-app-id-and-the-bundle-id-where-is-the-app-id

Answer (score 0):

If you change the bundle identifier then you will have to set it up as a new app. The bundle identifier is the unique ID for the app so without it all users who have downloaded the app would not receive the update and any metrics would also be lost.

There are a number of posts on forums regarding this such as the following:

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/14005

If you are changing the bundle identifier to associate the app with a different account then you should used a transfer request instead.

Answer (score 0):

App id always needs to be same in order to update same app in all release